# how to fix an element vertically only?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple table, with a head and a body. Now I want the head fixed, so that when the page scrolls vertically, you will always see the header. Now this is a problem for horizontal scrolling(on mobile devices with small screens). How do I fix it ONLY vertically?

Thank You

Comment: Does the page contain nothing but the table? Otherwise I can't imagine how the other content should behave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to make you header fixed

```
position:fixed;
top:0px;
left:0px;
```

if this doesn't work just create a div and put the header's info there and then add the above code